# MongoDB network keeps throwing this error

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, mongoose

Im getting an error while trying to connect to my MongoDB database, [This is the repo](https://github.com/SkyCryptWebsite/SkyCrypt).

This is the error I get while running the code -

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 52.20.9.178:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\SkyCrypt-development\SkyCrypt-development\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:306:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.kx9xv.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress {
          isIPv6: false,
          host: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.kx9xv.mongodb.net',
          port: 27017
        },
        address: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.kx9xv.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 7396352,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connection <monitor> to 52.20.9.178:27017 closed
            at Connection.onClose (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\SkyCrypt-development\SkyCrypt-development\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:138:19)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Downloads\SkyCrypt-development\SkyCrypt-development\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:65:46)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I've tried whitelisting my ip and other stuff and it still wont work. can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same type of error <-- node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:138:19) --->

I realized that in mongodb cluster I chose "Add current IP address" and when I edit it to "Allow access from Anywhere" my issue is resolved.
Maybe this can resolve your issue.

Follow the path:
Atlas-> Network Access -> IP Access List -> edit -> Allow Access from anywhere